# How to pass own executors to the redis lettuce library?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I have below code to get the data from Redis asynchronously. By default get() call in lettuce library uses nio-event thread pool.

Code 1:

```
StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection = redisClient.connect();
RedisAsyncCommands<String, String> command = connection.async();
CompletionStage<String> result = command.get(id)
        .thenAccept(code -> 
                     logger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread Id " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                     //Sample code to print thread ID
```

Thread Id printed is **lettuce-nioEventLoop-6-2**.

Code 2:

```
CompletionStage<String> result = command.get(id)
            .thenAcceptAsync(code -> {
                         logger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread Id " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
              //my original code
}, executors);
```

Thread Id printed is **pool-1-thread-1**.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to pass my executors?
2. Is it recommended approach to use nio-event thread pool to get(using get() call) the data from redis?

Lettuce version: *5.2.2.RELEASE*

thanks, 
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

class `io.lettuce.core.RedisClient` has a creator method:

```java
    public static RedisClient create(ClientResources clientResources, String uri) {
        assertNotNull(clientResources);
        LettuceAssert.notEmpty(uri, "URI must not be empty");
        return create(clientResources, RedisURI.create(uri));
    }
```

You can build your `ClientResources` by `ClientResources#builder()`, and pass anything you want. Refer the [JavaDoc](https://lettuce.io/core/release/api/io/lettuce/core/resource/ClientResources.html), there is something you can customize:

- EventLoopGroupProvider to obtain particular EventLoopGroups
- EventExecutorGroup to perform internal computation tasks
- Timer for scheduling
- EventBus for client event dispatching
- EventPublisherOptions
- CommandLatencyCollector to collect latency details. Requires the HdrHistogram library.
- DnsResolver to collect latency details. Requires the LatencyUtils library.
- Reconnect Delay.
- Tracing to trace Redis commands.